# NodeJs refer to object with string

Tags: javascript, node.js

At runtime, I need to take a string say 'TEST1' and get a reference to the object of the same name.

The object is created using modules.export and require. My attempt:

```
var TEST1 = require("./test1.js");
var TEST2 = require("./test2.js");

//TEST1.DoThings() is a function that exists now
//TEST2.DoThings() is a function that exists now


function DoIt(str){
    var obj = global[str];
    obj.DoThings() 
}

DoIt("TEST1") // fails
DoIt("TEST2") // fails
```

How can I call either function by using only a string as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside an Node.js module will be local to that module. Use following code instead

```
global.TEST1 = require('./test1.js');
global.TEST2 = require('./test2.js');


function DoIt(str){
var obj = global[str];
obj.DoThings();
}

DoIt('TEST1');
DoIt('TEST2');
```

**EDIT**

Because of editing global object is bad practice, you can solve it using two different ways. First way is to create variable where you will store imported modules and other objects you want to be accessed using string.

```
var imps = {};
imps.TEST1 = require('./test1.js');
imps.TEST2 = require('./test2.js');

function DoIt(str){
var obj = imps[str];
obj.DoThings();
}

DoIt('TEST1');
DoIt('TEST2');
```

Second way is to override `require` function to store all imported modules into `imps` variable (of course, if you want to add something other to `imps` variable, you need to do it like in the first example).

```
var imps = {};
require = function(a){
    return function(b, c){
        imps[b] = a(c);
    };
}(require);

require('TEST1', './test1.js');
require('TEST2', './test2.js');

function DoIt(str){
var obj = imps[str];
obj.DoThings();
}

DoIt('TEST1');
DoIt('TEST2');
```

Comment: Note: By attaching it to `global`, these variables [become available to *all* modules.](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects)

Comment: @MikeC. Why it should be a problem? OP has already written his code like global variables is part of the global object. Nobody usually override built-in keys of the global object as name of some imported module, so there is no danger of influencing module loading process.

Comment: OP was just taking a stab at how to do it but what they have doesn't work. I'm not worried about it influencing the module loading process (although I suppose that is a problem as well). It's that [you should really avoid global variables](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) whenever possible. Encapsulation is a very important concept in solid software engineering.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to store those objects in another object and reference them that way.

```js
var imports = {
  TEST1: { // in your case, do require('./test1.js')
    DoThings() {
      console.log('test1');
    }
  },
  TEST2: { // in your case, do require('./test1.js')
    DoThings() {
      console.log('test2');
    }
  }
};

function DoIt(str){
  // Get the objects from your dictionary
  var obj = imports[str];
  obj.DoThings() 
}

DoIt("TEST1") // fails
DoIt("TEST2") // fails
```